# How to find rectangular pattern coordinates in a 2d Matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have an integer 2d matrix(6,5) as below:

[image]

I need to find the count of all the rectangular pattern that contains 3 dots and are not overlapping with their co-ordinates.

This was a question which came to me in an interview which i didn't clear. Can any one help me with steps to follow so that i can create a program in c#.

Comment: What was your own attempt?

Comment: I just created a matrix with the dots specified but unable to get this rectangular pattern. I can't figure out how to loop like this.

Comment: What do you mean *not overlapping with their co-ordinates*?

Comment: Like in the above figure, the rectangles are not sharing same coordinates. In first rectangle (4,3) and second rectangle (3,3) the rectangles are not sharing same coordinates. If it was (3,3) for first rectangle and (3,3) for second rectangle then it would have resulted in overlapping.